# Do spark tasks(per executor) share cache location?

Tags: apache-spark

Do spark uses same cache location for storing tmp files per each executor

e.g., If I have two task running in one executor and both create a file with the same name, will one gives an error that "file exists"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from another source,

> It does use the same cache location, as per its spark local dirs
>   property, and io tmp dir for java stuff,
>
> if by create a file you mean like adding a file (addFile), then you
>   could overcome this by also setting spark.files.overwrite to true,
>   which will only work if the current file is different from the newly
>   added.